# Django - what timezone does auto_now use in a models.DateTimeField?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I need every datetime in my system to be on UTC time.  If I use auto_now, how can I ensure that it will set a python `datetime` with the `tzinfo` set to UTC?  I want to create a field as follows:

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    some_field        = models.ForeignKey(AnotherTable, null=False)
    last_modified_utc = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django has a [`TIME_ZONE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TIME_ZONE) settings in the `settings.py` file which it uses in the runtime to handle any datetime object.

> When USE_TZ is False, this is the time zone in which Django will store all datetimes. When USE_TZ is True, this is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms.

So, you can set it to `UTC` as it's one of the [valid timezones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).